# Dynamic Data Web Application give me error?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, ado.net

İ try to work Ado.net Entity Framework with dynamic Data web  Application But My solution run wthout error But Click gridview  items create me :

**Server Error in '/' Application. The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip'.**

Answer (score 3):

Old question, but ran into this yesterday, so I thought posting the solution would make sense: this error occurs if you have selected the wrong template in Visual Studio for your dynamic data project. There are 2 templates (actually 4, 2 for websites and 2 for web projects):

1. Dynamic data web application
2. Dynamic data *entities* web application

Use **1** with linq-to-sql, use **2** with Entity Framework. If you use the first template with EF, you get the aforementioned error.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks.

1. Dynamic data web application
2. Dynamic data entities web application

Use 1 with linq-to-sql, use 2 with Entity Framework. If you use the first template with EF, you get the aforementioned error.

This is the correct way to do it.